# How can I reuse Slick query

Tags: scala, slick

My table definitions are

```
class Ipv4ToCountries(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Long, String)](tag, "IP2COUNTRIES") {
  def ip = column[Long]("IP")
  def country = column[String]("COUNTRY")

  def * = (ip, country)
}

class Ipv6ToCountries(tag: Tag) extends Table[(BigDecimal, String)](tag, "IPV6_2COUNTRIES") {
  def ip = column[BigDecimal]("IP")
  def country = column[String]("COUNTRY")

  def * = (ip, country)
}

class Country2Languages(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, String, String)](tag, "COUNTRY2LANGUAGES") {
  def code = column[String]("CODE")
  def lang_code = column[String]("LANG_CODE")
  def iso_country = column[String]("ISO_COUNTRY")

  def * = (code, lang_code, iso_country)
}
```

Note that the only difference between `Ipv4ToCountries` and `Ipv6ToCountries` is the type of `ip` column. Here is my query function:

```
  def getLangCode(ip: String): Future[String] = {
    InetAddress.getByName(ip) match {
      case ipv4: Inet4Address =>
        val q = (for {
          i <- ipv4s.sortBy(_.ip.desc) if i.ip < ipv4ToLong(ipv4)
          c <- ip2nationCountries if i.country === c.code
        } yield c.lang_code).take(1)
        db.run(q.result.head)
      case ipv6: Inet6Address =>
        val q = (for {
          i <- ipv6s.sortBy(_.ip.desc) if i.ip < ipv6ToDecimal(ipv6)
          c <- ip2nationCountries if i.country === c.code
        } yield c.lang_code).take(1)
        db.run(q.result.head)
    }
  }
```

The query for IPv4 and IPv6 is almost identical but the condition `if i.ip < addrToNumeric`.

Is there any way to reuse the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a common parametrized class like

```
class IpToContries[A: TypeMapper](t: Tag, s: String) extends Table[(A, String)](t, s) {
  def ip = column[A]("IP")
  def country = column[String]("COUNTRY")

  def * = (ip, country)
}
```

and then use it like

```
class Ipv4Countries(tag: Tag) extends IpToContries[Long](tag, "IP2COUNTRIES")
class Ipv6Countries(tag: Tag) extends IpToContries[BigDecimal](tag, "IPV6_2COUNTRIES")
```

I haven't tested it, but the `TypeMapper` context bound on `A` should specify the generic type enough to be used in that fashion.

Comment: I confirm that this works fine. You can also define generic queries in a class like this: `class IpToContriesQueries[E <: IpToContries](val table: TableQuery[E]) {}`